# How to run a program in the context of a VRF in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, linux-networking, network-namespace

I have created a VRF and I have added interfaces and routes to my VRF. My VRF is as shown below.

My VRF is names wan1:

```
[root@host ~]# ip route list vrf wan1
default via 12.12.12.12 dev enp1s0.4025 
12.12.12.0/25 dev enp1s0.4025 proto kernel scope link src 12.12.12.1 
12.12.12.1 dev enp1s0.4025 scope link
```

My VRF can ping:

```
[root@host ~]# ping 8.8.8.8 -I wan1
ping: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than wan1.
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 12.12.12.12 wan1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=4.54 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=4.54 ms
```

However, when I try to start a program in my VRF, I get the following error:

```
[root@host ~]# ip vrf exec wan1 /usr/sbin/ssh root@1.2.3.4
Failed to mount cgroup2: No such file or directory
```

I know my kernel supports:

```
[root@host network-scripts]# cat /proc/filesystems 
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   configfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   dax
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   hugetlbfs
nodev   devpts
nodev   autofs
nodev   pstore
nodev   efivarfs
nodev   mqueue
nodev   selinuxfs
        xfs
        vfat
```

Any ideas why I am getting that error? I am running on Centos 7 with kernel 4.17.10-1

Thanks for any help

**EDIT:** here is the full stack trace:

```
[root@host tmp]# strace ip vrf exec wan1 /usr/sbin/ssh root@1.2.3.4
execve("/usr/sbin/ip", ["ip", "vrf", "exec", "wan1", "/usr/sbin/ssh", "root@1.2.3.4"], [/* 25 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1714000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa21313c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32868, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32868, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa213133000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa212d18000
mprotect(0x7fa212d1a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa212f1a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa212f1a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P%\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2173512, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3981792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa21294b000
mprotect(0x7fa212b0e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa212d0d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c2000) = 0x7fa212d0d000
mmap(0x7fa212d13000, 16864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa212d13000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa213132000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa213130000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa213130740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa212d0d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa212f1a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x669000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fa21313d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fa213133000, 32868)           = 0
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_NETLINK, 11, [1], 4)  = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=1736, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{",\0\0\0\22\0\1\0\347\305`[\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 44}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 44
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{NULL, 0}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 1316
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1714000
brk(0x1735000)                          = 0x1735000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1735000
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"$\5\0\0\20\0\0\0\347\305`[\310\6\0\0\0\0\1\0\6\0\0\0\301\4\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1316}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1316
open("/proc/mounts", O_RDONLY)          = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa21313b000
read(4, "sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nos"..., 1024) = 1024
read(4, "0 0\ncgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids c"..., 1024) = 1024
read(4, "emd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc a"..., 1024) = 580
read(4, "", 1024)                       = 0
read(4, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa21313b000, 4096)            = 0
stat("/var", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=800, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/run/cgroup2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40, ...}) = 0
mount("none", "/var/run/cgroup2", "cgroup2", 0, NULL) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Failed to mount cgroup2: No such"..., 51Failed to mount cgroup2:No such file or directory) = 51
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with VRF but looks like you have problems with mounting 
cgroup v2. According to documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt) command should be something like:

```
mount -t cgroup2 none $MOUNT_POINT
```

You can try to check where it tries to mount cgroupv2 with command:

```
strace -e trace=mount ip vrf exec wan1 /usr/sbin/ssh root@1.2.3.4
```

Maybe it is triyng to mount cgroup into non existing directory. But this is only my gues.

Comment: I haven't used strace before, but i got the following output:                 mount("none", "/var/run/cgroup2", "cgroup2", 0, NULL) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Failed to mount cgroup2: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++

Comment: I can confirm /var/run/cgroup2 does infact exist. It is an empty directory

Comment: and can you mount cgroup2 in that directory ? 
`mount -t cgroup2 none /var/run/cgroup2`

Comment: When I run that I get "mount: special device none does not exist".
When I run "mount -t cgroup2 cgroup /var/run/cgroup2
mount: special device cgroup does not exist".

Comment: this works. but mounting it doesnt resolve the error: "mount -t cgroup cgroup /tmp/ -o memory"